# how to write a update method to update each cell of a table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask

[image]I have scratched every single hair on my head, but able to come to any conclusion about writing an "UPDATE" query for a given scenario.
I have a request body coming from front-end as below

```
{"info": [
                {
                    "NaN": "From",
                    "From": "To",
                    "3.00000000": "8.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "11.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "14.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "17.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "20.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "23.00000000",
                    "key": 0
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "3.00000000",
                    "From": "8.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "13.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "18.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "23.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "28.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "33.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "38.00000000",
                    "key": 1
                }}
```

The UI looks like [image: this]

In the UI screenshot, the first two rows and first two columns are greyed out. and the cells in white area have to be updated.

In the DB, the columns are represented as below

```
COLUMN_FROM
COLUMN_TO
ROW_FROM
ROW_TO
```

I have written a below SQL query method. I am not at all sure that it will work.

```
def gp_table(self, info):
    query = ''

    for loop in info:
        query = f" UPDATE {self.TABLE_NAME} SET COLUMN_FROM = {[loop['3.00000000']]}, COLUMN_TO = {[loop['4.00000000']]}, ROW_FROM = {[loop['8.00000000"]]}, ROW_TO = {[loop['11.00000000']]} <WHERE CONDITION>;"
        print("[QUERY] :", query)

    return query
```

Note:

- info in the above code represents "info" from the request body.
- In the UI table,the the first two rows and first two columns will change if an user excel file. i.e. length of rows and columns may or may not differ, as well as the numbers shown in the screenshot will also differ.

Please suggest. I am stuck for 2 days now, but can't reach anywhere.

thank you

Error

```
{ "data": "Database Query execution error. {'code': None, 'stepId': None, 'message': 'SQL compilation error:\\nExpression type does not match column data type, expecting FLOAT but got ARRAY for column COLUMN_FROM', 'moreinfo': None}",
```

Comment: You make it sound like you haven't even tried to run the query...

Comment: yes, because I know the sql will fail

Comment: If you know the query will fail, you imply you know the error that will be returned as well (as you know what is incorrect). So why not fix the query?  Or better yet, run the query, see what error is returned (if it fails) and go from there...

Comment: I ran the query, and I got error which I have updated in main post.

Comment: I am not able to figure out that what would be the value for those 4 columns in sql query. As the data in the request body is  may or may not change.

Comment: Look closely at the error... it states that you are passing in an array for a parameter that must be a float.  Using your f-string you have your value in { } brackets.  Inside of there you have a value loop[3.00..], but you wrap this value in [ ] making it a list/array.

Comment: I am not sure you have understood my issue at all. Yu are focusing on error, while I am already said that my SQL query is not proper. Had I know the exact solution for my issue, I wouldn't have com here. I am not able to write my SQL query based on my scenario.. Plz focus on that if u want to help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253337/discussion-between-moldofdestiny-and-user3521180).